# Given a PDE show that the image lies in [0,1]

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given that:

$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u(x)&=ku^2(x)(1-u(x)),&\text{ if }x \in \Omega \\
\phantom{-}u(x)&=0,&\text{ if }x \in \partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$

and $k>0$ constant, show that $0 \leq u(x)\leq 1$.

I assumed that $\exists x_0 \in \Omega$ such as $u(x_0)>1$.

Using the conditions of maximum points of a function, by the Jacobian and Hessian of $u$, I showed that

$u_{xx}<0$ and $u_{yy}<0$ but a I couldn't  find something about $u_{zz}$.

If I find that $u_{zz}<0$ then $-\Delta u(x_0)>0$ but $ku^2(x_0)(1-u(x_0))<0$ contradiction.

So $0\leq u(x)\leq 1$.

Comment: Assume $x_0$ is a local max, then $D^2u(x_0)\leq 0$ and so $\Delta u = tr(D^2u)\leq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x_0$ is a maximum point, then the function of a real variable $t \mapsto u(x_0 + t e_i)$ has a maximum at $t = 0$, so you shall have $\partial_{ii} u < 0$. No need for arguments with the Hessian matrix.